# using jQuery's getJSON with Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, getjson

i am new to jquery and zend, trying to use $.getJSON to communicate between the front end and the back end.

so here is what i did:

in the /mycontroller/index.phtml's header tag, i have js code:

```
 <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //  alert("js");
        $("#loadQuestions").submit(function(){
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(formData);
            $.getJSON('http://xxx.com/mycontroller/process', formData, processData).error('ouch');
            function processData(data){
                //alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
            return false;
        }); // end submit
    }); // end ready
</script>
```

in the body tag, there is a simple form:

```
<form action="http://xxx.com/mycontroller/process" method="post" id="loadQuestions">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="100">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

in the processAction(), there are simple codes:

```
$arr = array('pageNumber'=>200);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit;
```

what i suppose to have is that after i hit submit, the form data should be gathered(and i can see in the chrome console), but after i saw the formData, there is nothing shown in the console again(i should see the data passed from server but i did not).

Does anybody have an idea what i should do to fix it?

Comment: this link rocks: http://www.zendcasts.com/making-json-objects-from-zend_controllers-using-jquery/2009/02/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a problem because you're trying to print from the controller. In Zend, you have to do that in the view file.

So... in the processAction  you should do something like...

```
$this->view->data = $arr;
```

Then in the view file process.phtml you need...

```
if($this->data)
    echo json_encode($this->data);
```

Comment: I disable the action's view and echo in the action. thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AjaxContext action helper in your controller.

I set it up like this.

```
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->_ajaxContentSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
        $this->_ajaxContentSwitch->addActionContext('process', 'json')
                                 ->initContext();
   }
```

And in your process action.

```
public function processAction()
{
    if ($this->_helper->ajaxContext()->getCurrentContext() == 'json') { 
                $this->view->array = array('pageNumber'=>200);
    } else {
        // Not called via ajax do redirect or something here
    }
}
```

Also the url in your JQuery script should be "http://xxx.com/mycontroller/process/format/json" for this to work.

The above processAction will return a json string called array containing your array.

I hope this helps.

Garry